# setState array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

How to avoid setState with loop? I have this

`const here = [{a: 'abc'},{b: 'xyz'}]`

I do `this.setState({'some_other_key':123, ...here})` it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You typically set state not on the entire object but just the key that you want to change. Typical example would be this.setState({some_other_key: 2})

Answer (score 1):

You only need to provide those element to setState that you wish to change and not the other ones and hence you only need

```
 this.setState({'some_other_key':123})
```

`setState` performs a merge and hence if the key exists, its value is changes, if it doesn't exist a new one is created and all the other ones are kept as they are.

In order to add an object to the setState array, you could do the following

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    exist: [...prevState.exist, {'some_other_key':123}]
}))
```

Comment: I need to set `exist variable`, maybe the naming is confusing.

Comment: changed naming btw.

Comment: Jane, as I understand you need to set the array to the state and append an object to it, I updated my answer to do the same

Comment: prevState.exist? it's not exist yet, will it cause error?

Comment: can you ignore 'exist'? I've changed the naming .

Comment: My question is how to not use loop.

Answer (score 0):

try `const exist = {{a: 'abc'},{b: 'xyz'}}`

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation of your solution would improve the general usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the loop?
If you have 
`const here = {a:'abc', b:'xyz'}`
Then `this.setState({'some_other_key':123, ...here})` should work.

If `const here = [{a: 'abc'},{b: 'xyz'}]`
Then `{'some_other_key':123, ...here}` is

`{
    'some_other_key': 123,
    0: {a: 'abc'},
    1: {b: 'xyz'}
}`

If `const here = {a: 'abc', b: 'xyz'}`
Then `{'some_other_key':123, ...here}` is

`{
    'some_other_key': 123,
    a: 'abc',
    b: 'xyz'
}`
This is how the spread operator '...' works.